# How do I connect my 24 pin fpc to dip breakout board to my rpi zero w?

Tags: rpi.gpio, display, driver, lcd, adafruit

So I am working on a type of headset and I bought the adafruit 1.3 ips with 24 pin fpc connector and st7789 driver and I'm thinking of using a breakout board to do it. What I don't know is the pin out to connect the breakout board to the gpio.

Comment: How to connect to a fpc cable has nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of doing this:

Normally if it's only a few connectors then DuPont cables are used.  These are short cables (about 15-20cm is the longest I have) With ether male (sordid metal) pins or female (plastic block with metal grips in it) ends on them  Care needs to be taken as some of the cheap ones are thing and do not push in to the breadboard very well.

If you need lots of connectors then you can get extension cables that look like the old PATA hard or floppy disk cables. These come with a female block for the Pi and and slip into the breadboard in a long set of male ends.

Another way is to use a T-Shaped connector. The top part goes on the Pi and the downward arm goes into the board allowing you to jumper from that.

A surf on the large suppliers of Pi computers (Pimoroni, ThePiHut, Adafruit) will show all of these and more.

For flexibility I would just start with a set of decent DuPont jumper cables (M-M, M-F and F-F) of mixed lengths.  You can buy these as a set or even in a box - a box is handy as these get strewn around the desk and drawers in a very untidy fashion here :-)

Comment: I have that but the problem is figuring out the pi out. Sorry I should have been more specific.